# Reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 from USB- It is the only OS on my system.

Tags: uninstall, delete, reinstall

I am a very novice Ubuntu user, and there were some issues when I first installed Ubuntu. I would like to reinstall it from my USB, but I can't figure out how to do this even after reading through the forums. Also, when I first installed Ubuntu I had to restart the computer and at this point I had a black screen for a very long time, is this normal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The black screen may have been a prompt for you to enter your encryption password - just a guess from experience. Otherwise it may have been a video card problem or one of many other problems.

Alright so lets move forward to get you back on your feet.  What computer are you using?

If you are in a rush, just try to reinstall - post any further questions here.

Comment: I am using a gigabyte brix mini pc

Comment: It was initially a barebone pc so the only OS that I currently have is Ubuntu

Comment: Try to reinstall then. If you set any passwords during the install process keep track of them and if you come across a black screen type it in and press enter. Otherwise, if you have any questions post it here.

Comment: how do I reinstall

Comment: thats the part that I am struggling with thanks

Comment: Do you have ubuntu on a bootable usb stick? Instructions here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Here is the installation guide: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: If I follow the install options will this take care of the one thats currently installed?

Comment: Yes, during the install process it will ask whether to override the entire disk or to install alongside the currently installed ubuntu. Select the first option - override the entire disk.

Answer (score 0):

On a second computer, download Universal USB installer through here: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/
Then, install the ubuntu iso you wanted. (I recommend 14.04.2 or 15.04)
When it is done, open universal usb installer and select ubuntu, then select the ubuntu iso and apply to format as FAT32.
Now all you need to do is wait for it to be done.
Just now, when it is done, close the program and unplug the USB from the second machine and put the USB in the one you want ubuntu to be reinstalled.
Then boot the computer that you want ubuntu to be reinstalled.
Now, go to the boot menu and select your usb. If it does not show, unplug the USB and then put it back in and reboot.
Then select the Try Ubuntu option if you want to try Ubuntu, or install ubuntu if you want to install it. You can also test RAM by running memtest 86+.
If you want to install, choose your things then choose to reinstall ubuntu, if it does not show then go to the partition thing and delete the partitions ubuntu has (should be ext4 for ubuntu and swap for ubuntu swap, however you don't need to delete swap) and if you will not delete swap, just make a ext4 partition selected (a thing i dont remember) /. If you delete both make a swap parition and a ext4 partition (where ubuntu will be installed) with the / thing.
Now just select the ext4 partition and continue, select the things you wanted.
Now ubuntu will start installing.
Now when it says to restart, click on the restart button. Now you have ubuntu installed. Now you can format your usb and unplug it.